# about rolls and being forced to reroll

Tags: king-of-tokyo

If I'm rolling dice in King of Tokyo, I get what I want after 2 rolls, and I choose not to take my 3rd roll. Another person has a card that says they may make someone reroll a die once each turn. If they make me roll a die after those two rolls, and I don't like the result, may I then take my 3rd roll?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are talking about Psychic Probe as the card forcing the reroll.

Based on the English translation of the French faq from [Boardgame Geek](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/743476/faq-in-english-answered-by-gabriel-iello-in-a-fren):

> *Psychic probe:* If you still have rerolls left, you cannot use them after a psychic probe effect (which takes place the moment you declare that you keep the dice results).